# PhpStorm error highlights in *.php files

Tags: ide, phpstorm

Please can someone help me with **PhpStorm** issues?
Recently the IDE has started to show multiple errors in my code, though it seems to be fine. Errors sounds like "Expected: semicolon", "Expected statement". Intellisense does not work for such files either.
I didn't make any changes to the IDE settings.

[image]

I use the 7.0 version.
Thanks.

Comment: `File | Invalidate Caches` ?

Comment: @LazyOne, unfortunately, it didn't help

Comment: Have you restarted IDE after that? Is there anything special about this file? Can you show screenshot of whole file (including editor tab)? Do you have such issues with any other files?

Comment: @LazyOne, this bug appears not every time I run the IDE. If I see it again, I'll make a bigger screenshot. To my mind checking rules have broken somehow.